# Inlining Modules In Typescript

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I would like to use modules in TypeScript for inlining purposes. For example, if I have this code in mymodule.ts:

```
export class mymodule {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Hi');
    }
}
```

When I include this class in another file with:

```
import { mymodule } from './mymodule.ts'
```

I would like to have the mymodule class copy-and-pasted or inlined to compiled file. I am using outFile option to compile to single file but it just creates multiple modules in one file, generating unnecessary wrapper codes. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this frontend or backend code?

Comment: At first glance, it seems you might consider using Webpack to build what you need or maybe a clever use of Typescript decorators....perhaps you might ask yourself why you are using a copy-n-paste (or include file) approach

Comment: This post might be worth reading if you are still considering that approach: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4691

Comment: require would probably be better for this.

Answer (score 4):

## Let's start with JavaScript

[Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) does what you need but with JavaScript.

For example, here is a class:

```
// MyClass.js
export class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Hi');
    }
}
```

And the entry point:

```
// main.js
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';
export const inst = new MyClass();
```

Then, install Rollup and run it:

```
npm install rollup
./node_modules/.bin/rollup main.js --o bundle.js --f es
```

Rollup produces the following file:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Hi');
    }
}

const inst = new MyClass();

export { inst };
```

[Try it here.](https://rollupjs.org/repl?version=0.57.1&shareable=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)

## With TypeScript

There are two solutions:

1. Use *tsc* to compile each TypeScript file to a JavaScript file, then use Rollup (this is what I do);
2. Or, use a plugin for Rollup.

Regarding the second solution, since the [official Rollup plugin](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-typescript) use a legacy version of TypeScript, I suggest to give a try to [rollup-plugin-typescript2](https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2).

If you use a Rollup plugin, then a configuration file for Rollup (`rollup.config.js`) will be required.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called [scope hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), and there is no way (at the moment) to do it with the Typescript compiler alone. You will need to use Typescript + Rollup/Webpack in order to achieve that.

The gist is you need to modify your `tsconfig.json` to output ES2015 modules, which you will then pass to the bundler of your choice to combine them into a single file.

Note, in Webpack scope hoisting is performed by the ModuleConcatenationPlugin, which is *only* included for production builds by default.